# Как заставить Vite собрать проект, который можно запустить без веб-сервера?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite

Есть проект на Vue, собираемый через Vite. При сборке он добавляет итоговый `main.js` в `head` c атрибутом `type='module'`. Если открыть `dist/index.html` локально без веб-сервера, то получим ошибку CORS при подключении скрипта, потому что он модуль.

Если отредактировать `dist/index.html` после сборки, убрать `type='module'` и поместить скрипт перед закрывающим `body` проект стартует без проблем и всё работает.

Но если убрать `type='module'` из исходного `src/index.html` проект не соберётся с варнингом:

```
<script src="./src/main.js"> in "/index.html" can't be bundled without type="module" attribute
```

`vite.config.js` выглядит так:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
    base: "" //нужны относительные пути
})
```

Как заставить Vite собрать без модуля в **выходном** `index.html`?